# SPServices UpdateListItems Will Not Update Target List

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I'm trying to copy items from a list in one site and update/paste them into a list in another site, but I can't get it to work. Please help. I have my references to jQuery and SPServices in the master page, so that's why you don't see them here.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function getItems()
{
    $().SPServices({
        operation: 'GetListItems',
        listName: '{79F42AED-47C1-4CDD-840D-748DF70694B7}',
        CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields Properties="True"/>',
        completefunc: function(xData, Status)
        {
            $(xData.responseXML).find('[nodeName["z:row"]').each(function()
            {
               var fmsCategory = $(this).attr('ows_Category');
               var fmsCase = $(this).attr('ows_Case');
               var fmsPm = $(this).attr('ows_PM');
               var fmsTotalValue = $(this).attr('ows_Total_x0020_Case_x0020_Value');
               var fmsUndeliveredValue = $(this).attr('ows_Undelivered_x0020_Value');
               var fmsSystem = $(this).attr('ows_System'); 

               updateItems(fmsCategory, fmsCase, fmsPm, fmsTotalValue, fmsUndeliveredValue, fmsSystem);
             });
          }
      });
}

function updateItems(fmsCategory, fmsCase, fmsPm, fmsTotalValue, fmsUndeliveredValue, fmsSystem)
{
    $().SPServices(
    {
        operation: 'UpdateListItems',
        webURL: 'http://intranet/sites/dashboard/peo/fms',
        listName: '{4EE12A8F-9C93-4B9A-8F71-2F809779329E}',
        updates: '<Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="True">' + 
            '<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">' +
            '<Field Name="Category">'+ fmsCategory +'</Field>' +
            '<Field Name="Case">'+ fmsCase +'</Field>' +
            '<Field Name="PM">'+ fmsPm +'</Field>' +
            '<Field Name="Total Case Value">'+ fmsTotalValue +'</Field>' +
            '<Field Name="Undelivered Value">'+ fmsUndeliveredValue +'</Field>' +
            '<Field Name="System">'+ fmsSystem +'</Field>' +
            '</Method>' +
         '</Batch>',
         completefunc: function(xData, Status)
         {
              alert('FMS Products List has successfully copied.');      
         }
    });
}
</script>
<input type='button' id='clone' value='Clone List' onclick='getItems()'></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using the Display Name in some of the `<Field Name>` updateItems function. Changed to Static Names and it works.